# How do I make an image fixed under the rest of the site?

Tags: html, css, image, fixed

I saw a site, bdplaw.com, and it has images (not background images) that stay fixed in their frame so that the rest of the site is built on top of the image and as you scroll it reveals more or less of the image within it's window.

How do I create this effect? I know how to make a background image stationary, but this is not a background image...yet it appears to be behind everything else.

Thanks

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed;` ?

Comment: What's the advantage of not having it be a bg image?

Comment: It is a background image, just check that sites source

Answer (score 2):

Here's a demo of the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/ewnZY/2/

### HTML

```
<div class="window" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/500);"></div>

<div class="window" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/800);"></div>
```

### CSS

```
.window {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin-top: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

Setting the `background-attachment` to `fixed` means that the image does not move even though the page does. Imagine sticking a post-it note to your monitor and scrolling a webpage behind. That post-it note isn't going anywhere :P

Answer (score 0):

below is CSS from that site which makes that background work like that.

```
background-image: url("http://www.bdplaw.com/content/themes/burnet-theme/img/xhome-bg1.jpg.pagespeed.ic.1DhW7PoqtC.jpg")

background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: 50% 0;
background-repeat: none;
position: relative;
```

Comment: So how does it appear to be behind everything else? Or, I guess a better way to put it, how do you get everything else in front of it?

Comment: because its "background-image" which means its on the background :)

but... you must apply this background to the top most container ofc